# Changing the background-color of a jQuery dialog with CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery UI dialog without theme. It shows like this:

[image]

Now I would like the background color of my form to be different. I already try this:

```
.ui-widget-content
{
    background-color: #ededed !important;
}
```

But the result is not very pretty (we see white parts on borders):

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: search for `border` and `padding` of the parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the elements out with firebug or a similar debugging tool - that will show you what you're missing. My guess is that's another element as the white spots are on the sides and don't look like a part of the main element.